# how HTTP set destination port when that site don't use port 80?

Tags: tcp, port

as i know it's possible to host so many web site on same computer with specific ip address, with different port for ex:80,81,82,..  so when some client wants to see that site ,dns give the IP address , but how clients find port number especially when port of that site don't set on 80

Comment: When hosting multiple sites on the same server IP, it is easier to utilize the HTTP 1.1 `Host` request header so they can all run on the same port.  Using different ports per site wastes resources unless you are hosting only a few sites.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

Please see the document http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

You use syntax like this:

```
http://<host name>:<port number>/path...
```

e.g.

```
http://www.mycompany.com:8081/index.html
```

Comment: so when we are in shared ip host for example "20.40.50.60" and we have two domain mycompany1.com and mycompany2.com and both of them have index.html     so conflict will happend after dns translate domain to ip :20.40.50.60:8081/index.html  this adress will refer to which site?